# Trouble Binding class to grid, second place

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

So I'm trying to create my own music player. 
I have a Listview updating properly with current playlist.
My problem begins when I want a grid to show the song which is currently playing.
When binding to those strings they all return `Null`.

From Class:

```
public class Song : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    //public ImageBrush Portrait { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public Song(string title, string path, string artist, int time, string album)//, ImageBrush portrait)
    {
        this.Path = path;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Artist = artist;
        this.Time = time;
        this.Album = album;
        //this.Portrait = portrait;
    }

    public string SongCurrentPlaying
    {
        get { return Title; }
        set
        {
            Title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SongCurrentPlaying");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Title));
        }
    }
```

From XAML:

```
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="143" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="124" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Songs.Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SongCurrentPlaying.Title, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Song.Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Songs.Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
        </Grid>
```

As you can see I've been experimenting on different bindings to get values from Title as example, none has been successful.

Comment: Does it only return `null` for `SongCurrentPlaying`?

Comment: Yes it does. Datacontext is null

Answer (score 0):

Your class structure does not make much sense. You have a `Song` class that holds a `Song`'s information. However, that class also holds `SongCurrentPlaying`. Now, if you *mean* to have `SongCurentPlaying` on the same class as `Song` then I would narrow down your issue to how you have performed the XAML bindings. I would assume that the `DataContext` of your control has not been set to an instance of `Song`. e.g.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var someSong = new Song(...);
        this.DataContext = someSong;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Once set as the `DataContext` you may then bind to the class' properties directly (e.g. `{Binding Title}`).

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to resolve the issue. One of my experiments was creating `SongCurrentPlaying` inside `Song`, have also tried with different class which failed.
You can't set it datacontext to `Song`

Answer (score 0):

Your song class does not need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You should think of your songs as models. Instead you should be making a viewmodel for your music player that will hold all your information for your view such as in this case `CurrentSongPlaying`.

I would make a `viewmodel` that looks like this

```
internal class SongPlayerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private Song _songPlaying;

public Song SongPlaying
{
  get { return _songPlaying; }
  set { 
    _songPlaying = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("SongPlaying");
  }
}



protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
  var handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null)
  {
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
}
```

}

Then make sure to set the `datacontext` to an instance of this in the view and inside of the xaml just bind the the title with code like this.

datacontext setup

```
private readonly SongPlayerViewModel _viewModel = new SongPlayerViewModel();

public MainWindow() 
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = _viewModel;
}
```

example xaml binding for current song playing

```
<TextBlock text="{Binding SongPlaying.Title}"/>
```

If you want something when no song is playing look into `Fallbackvalue`

Comment: How can I set datacontext to this? doesn't seem to be able to.

Comment: Have you never set a datacontext before? Its just as simple as it sounds ill update the main post with the initializing datacontext.

Comment: But the datacontext is already set to self in public mainwindow. Since my listview needs to be bound to another class then the view model